# React Native: Could not find auto-linked framework 'Razorpay' IOS

Tags: react-native, razorpay

Getting error as , "Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Razorpay' in IOS

[image]

Version:
**React Native**: 0.59.8
**react-native-razorpay**: 2.1.31 
Xcode : 11

Comment: Seems like razorpay team is least interested